# Mapping a primary key as foreign key in database

Tags: database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a logical problem in my database design. 
I have got a table with 2 field, one of the integer field is the primary key and it acts as foreign key in all other tables.

The table structure is

1. A table with an ID as primary key
2. ID may have the basic data types as values
3. Based on these data types the tables are mapped to the main table having ID as primary key

How can I map this in the database creation? How can i design the table with this requirement.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: java db is supposed to be used

Comment: You say _ID may have the basic data types as values_ - do you really mean that the ID might be an integer or might be a string or might be a date etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

standard SQL  can handle such a  mapping simply:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    first_name varchar,
    last_name varchar,
    date_started date,
    id int primary key
);
create table salary (
    employee_id int primary key references employee(id),
    yearly_amount numeric
);
CREATE TABLE wage (
    employee_id int primary key references employee(id),
    hourly_amount numeric
 );
```